# Executing command line code in an ant build file

Tags: ant, doctrine, hudson

How can I execute following command line code in an ant build file?

```
    cd backend/doctrine/
    export PC_ZEND_ENV=testing
    php doctrine migrations:migrate << EOF
    y
    EOF
```

**The solution**

With the feedback I've got I figured out the following working exec command.

```
<exec dir="backend/doctrine" executable="php">
    <env key="PC_ZEND_ENV" value="development" />
    <arg line="doctrine migrations:migrate" />
    <arg value="&lt;&lt; Y" />
</exec>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html). The result should be something like the following (untested):

```
<exec dir="backend/doctrine" executable="./doctrine">
    <arg line="migrations:migrate << EOF"/>
    <env key="PC_ZEND_ENV" value="testing"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: Thx this helped me allot further. Now I only have a problem with the << sign.

Comment: @Skelton, you could try escaping the `<<` by using `&lt;&lt;`.

Comment: Ant scripts are based on xml. You cannot use the signs >, <, & by themselves. They are like keywords. You have to use &lt;, &gt;, and &amp;